# How to read a .txt file into R as a vector with each word in its own row / line

Tags: r, text-mining, readfile

Title basically says it. I'd like to read a .txt file into R where all whitespace and punctuation is effectively turned into line breaks, splitting the words into a vector or single-column dataframe where the number of rows equals the number of words in the text file.

Comment: Look at the `readr` package

Answer (score 1):

I would read in the file first and then split the lines into words:

```
lines <- readLines("C:/Users/Johannes Gruber/Documents/Github/boellhessen/test.txt")
words <- strsplit(lines, " ")[[1]]
head(words)
#> [1] "Title"     "basically" "says"      "it."       "I'd"       "like"
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `tokenizers`, which is faster and more accurate.

```r
better_words <- tokenizers::tokenize_words(lines, lowercase = FALSE, strip_punct = FALSE)[[1]]
head(better_words)
#> [1] "Title"     "basically" "says"      "it"        "."         "I'd"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>